# How do I use multiple dedicated IPs to browse the web on my VPS?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, vps

I have an Ubuntu desktop installation on my VPS. How do I browse the net switching between my 2 dedicated IPs given to me by my host? How do I set it up?

Answer (score 1):

Use your VPS as a socks proxy. [Here](http://dimitar.me/dynamic-port-forwarding-with-socks-over-ssh/) is a tutorial on how to do it with putty